# Error: Compiler limit Heap limit reached on simple hello world program

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++-6

I am getting this error of, *"Heap limit reached use /Zm to specify a higher limit",* even when building an empty or hello world program in **VC6**. Can any one take me out of this trouble?

Comment: Buying more RAM might help ;)

Comment: Asked 14 years too late.  Which probably has something to do with the trouble.  Trying running it in a virtual machine that boots something old like Windows 2000 or XP.

Comment: @HansPassant: lolll XP isn't *that* old... it's the only [usable] version before Windows 7. :P

Comment: @shoayb: Try using the [Windows 2003 DDK](https://connect.microsoft.com/site148/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=21028) instead. It's newer but still similar to VC6.

Comment: Your question as it stands isn't answerable. Your compiler obviously isn't installed right, is corrupt, isn't compatible with your system, etc. But you've provided no details! Like, which OS are you running? On a real machine, or VM? How much RAM? Etc. Basic PC troubleshooting info.

Comment: Ram is 512 mb and Pentium 4 2.00 ghz. No vm but directly installed on pc

Comment: @HansPassant I have to do my project on machine not virtually.:(

Comment: That's not much of a machine by today's standards but it's enough better than the minimum that there shouldn't be a problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336439

Comment: What kind of vc6 project is it?

Answer (score 1):

Disable precompiled headers.
Go to project/properties to change it.

Or you can specify a higher heap for it using the /Zm command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

(the documentation is for vs8.0, but should work for vc too).